# Can filter views be applied on ranges given to formulas?

Tags: filter, google-sheets

Is there a way to make ranges passed to formulas to be filtered as it is diplayed when using filter views ?

E.G. data :

```
A | B | C
A | C | D
C | D | E
E | E | G
```

If filter view would be A:A = C I would like that COUNTA(A:A) to be 1 and not 4.

Answer (score 2):

To count the filtered data use:

```
=subtotal(3,A:A)
```

Comment: I'm looking for something similar but this does not do the deed for me as I do not use raw ranges but filtered ones, e.g. :

    COUNT(FILTER(Amounts, Operations="Deposit", Bookies=H2))

Any chances there is a function I could apply to Amounts range to discard filtered data ?